# Why are the Peano axioms axioms for natural numbers if they have non-standard models?

Tags: model-theory, peano-axioms

Why are the Peano axioms axioms for natural numbers  if they have non-standard models?
Shouldn't axioms determine an object up to isomorphism?

Comment: Why do you think they should do that?

Comment: In  non-standard model of natural numbers, does the Peano axiom about induction hold?

Comment: @coffeemath they wouldn't be called models of the Peano axioms if they don't respect  all of them, right?

Comment: The **second order** Peano axioms **do** characterize the natural numbers up to isomorphism. The **first order** Peano axioms don't because they can't; there are non-standard models which are elementarily equivalent to the natural numbers, meaning they satisfy all the same first order sentences as the natural numbers, including the first order Peano axioms.

Comment: @bof otherwise they should be called properties of the natural numbers instead.

Comment: The axioms of a vector space don't characterize vector spaces up to isomorphism. The axioms of group theory don't characterize groups up to isomorphism.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Very structure that verifies the axioms of groups is a group. But only not all structures that verify the Peano axioms of natural numbers are the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could you write this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Jiu "[Every] structure that verifies the axioms of groups is a group. But only not all structures that verify the Peano axioms of natural numbers are the set of natural numbers." The point is that the group axioms do **not** pin down any particular group up to isomorphism ("Shouldn't axioms determine an object up to isomorphism?"). So if you have no problem calling the group axioms such, why do the (first-order) Peano axioms get treated differently?

Comment: I would somewhat agree with you if the PA axioms were called "the natural number axioms" instead - which they sometimes are, and which I disapprove of - but the term "Peano axioms" doesn't inherently suggest a unique model. Incidentally, by [the compactness theorem in the form of the upwards Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Upward_part) *no* infinite structure can be pinned down up to isomorphism by a first-order theory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks form making me aware of this theorem. I asked this question because I read somewhere that the Peano axioms are the axiomatic definition of natural numbers, and somewhere else that they have non standard models.

Comment: @Jiu Ah, that is confusing! That sounds like the first author is referring to the second-order version of PA without saying so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original formulation of [Peano-Dedekind axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation) corresponds to modern Second Order Logic version.

[Richard Dedekind](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dedekind-foundations/#FouAri) in *The Nature and Meaning of Numbers* (*Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen?* (1888)),  proved that they characterize the natural numbers up to isomorphism.